# PHP code Error in_array

Tags: php

I am getting this code error on a PHP

```
   class Utils
 {
  static public $actionPath = 'install/core/actions';

  static public function checkActionExists($actionName)
  {
    return in_array($actionName, [
        'applySett',
        'buildDatabase',
        'checkPermission',
        'createUser',
        'errors',
        'finish',
        'main',
        'setEmailSett',
        'setPreferences',
        'settingsTest',
        'setupConfirmation',
        'step1',
        'step2',
        'step3',
        'step4',
        'step5'
    ]);


    return false;
  }
 }
```

According to Dreamweaver the error is on the first line of this snippet. The error I am getting trying to run the code is as follow:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home//test/install/core/Utils.php on line 36

I am trying to install an open source software ESPO CRM

Comment: definitely your version of php is outdated. Either upgrade, or use `array()`.

Comment: Why do you have 2 returns in the same function with no logic between them?

Comment: I see I was running 5.3 Ver will change it to latest and try again

Comment: @Dez i did not write the code was part of opensource. Fred thanks looks like that worked no errors